# Commit status publisher error persists after being deleted

Tags: teamcity

I tried to add the Build Feature: Commit status publisher. However received the below error. It's most likely that my user does not have access and I decided to investigate this at a later stage. I deleted the Build feature expecting the relevant error to go away.
However now the error persists and I can't seem to get rid of it. How can I remove this error?

> Publish status error in build #1.1.170.0 {build id=2622, buildTypeId=MyPipeline_UiTests}: Cannot publish status to Bitbucket Cloud for VCS root MyVcsRoot: response code: 400, reason: BAD REQUEST, message: 'Bad request. Field 'url': Enter a valid URL.'

Any help is appreciated.

**Additional Info:**

- I use Bitbucket (not the owner of the repository)
- TeamCity: 10.0.1
- VCS Authentication method: Uploaded Key (ssh)
- Commit status publisher: 42078